# encryption/decryption with user input

Tags: python, encryption

Idk why this is not outputing to the file, any ideas or help?

```
def encrypt(text, key):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    text = text.lower()
    cipherText = ""
    for ch in text:
        idx = alphabet.find(ch)
        cipherText = cipherText + key[idx]
    return cipherText

def decrypt(cipherText, key):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    cipherText = cipherText.lower()
    text = ""
    for ch in cipherText:
        idx = key.find(ch)
        text = text + alphabet[idx]
    return text

def main():
    userInput = input("Operation (encrypt, decrypt, exit): ")
    while(userInput != "exit"):
        if(userInput == "encrypt"):
            in_file = open(input("Input file name: "), 'r')
            out_file = open(input("Output file name: "), 'w')
            password = input("Password: ")
            for line in in_file:
                read_line = in_file.readline()
                encrypted_line = encrypt(read_line, password)
                out_file.write(encrypted_line)
                print(encrypted_line)
            in_file.close()
            out_file.close()

        elif(userInput == "decrypt"):
            in_file = open(input("Input file name: "), 'r')
            out_file = open(input("Output file name: "), 'w')
            password = input("Password: ")
            for line in in_file:
                read_line = in_file.readline()
                decrypted_line = decrypt(read_line, password)
                out_file.write(decrypted_line)
                print(decrypted_line)
            in_file.close()
            out_file.close()

        else:
            print("Invalid choice!")
        userInput = input("Operation (encrypt, decrypt, exit): ")

main()
```

Comment: What is the question? Please don't throw code at our heads without given information what this code is doing or should do.

Comment: are you getting any traceback? Is print(decrypted_line) printing something?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 tracks to be followed:

- use `raw_input`, which returns a string, instead of `input` that returns a function (that invalidates your tests `userInput == "decrypt"` and similar)
- `for line in in_file:` is enough to browse a file, you don't need to add `read_line = in_file.readline()`